# Persisting in a NativeActivity hosted in IIS

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, persist

I've created a native activity that promotes one or more properties using a persistence participant, and the information gets persisted to the database the next time a persist activity is used in the parent workflow. What I'd really like is to add an AutoPersist property to my native activity so that I can choose for the data to be persisted instantly to the database, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've seen it done by making calls to the underlying workflow host, but I don't think I have access to that when I'm running my workflow in IIS. I get uncatchable (unless someone can tell me different) errors when I try to schedule a persist activity after completing my native activity and a similar result when I create a composite activity containing my native activity and a persist.

Is there something I'm missing? I suppose the error I can't catch might give me more of a clue to what I'm doing wrong, but I would have thought that the composite activity would work. I'm beginning to think that a persist can only be done in a workflow thread - can anyone confirm or deny that?

Any help much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Persisting can only happen at activity boundaries, so you won't be able to schedule a persist from inside the execute method of your native activity.

What exception do you get when you put a Persist after your native activity?